# an error "undefined reference to 'log4cplus::Logger::operator=(log4cplus::Logger&&)'"

Tags: c++11, g++, log4cplus

Now there is a problem when i want to compile a project which needs to ld `liblog4cplus.a`
When i use the compile option `-std=c++11` ,then there's an error

> Undefined reference to 'log4cplus::Logger::operator=(log4cplus::Logger&&)'

but whole project needs the option `-std=c++11`
So how can i solve this problem?

PS : Compiled on `Ubuntu 12.04` ,which `gcc version:4.8.2` and `liblog4cplus version:1.1.3`

Comment: Is the library compiled with C++11 enabled? My guess is that it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile *both* your code and log4cplus library with or without the `-std=c++11` flag. Mixed compilations are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

#### my solution:

`log4cplus::Logger g_piano_logger;
    auto logger = log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(...
    g_logger = logger;`

#### or rebuild log4cplus

note `LOG4CPLUS_HAVE_RVALUE_REFS` in log4cplus-1.1.1/include/log4cplus/logger.h

`Logger& operator=(const Logger& rhs);
    #if defined (LOG4CPLUS_HAVE_RVALUE_REFS)
            Logger (Logger && rhs);
            Logger & operator = (Logger && rhs);
    #endif`